# Merge/Synonym request: [caliburn] and [caliburn.micro]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

They both refer to the same [framework](http://caliburnmicro.com/), since the official name for the framework is Caliburn.Micro I propose to file/retag/synonymize(sp?) it all under the [caliburn.micro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caliburn.micro) tag.

The wiki for [caliburn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caliburn) also refers to http://www.caliburnproject.com/ which seems to be no longer in use by the project.

Stats:

- [caliburn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caliburn) has 142 questions and 27 followers
- [caliburn.micro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caliburn.micro) has 1.166 questions and 201 followers

Even more, there are quite a few questions that refer to both tags:

- [Caliburn Micro and ContextMenu results in target not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256065/caliburn-micro-and-contextmenu-results-in-target-not-found)
- [Caliburm Micro Conductors opening other conductors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199066/caliburm-micro-conductors-opening-other-conductors)
- [How do I configure Caliburn for an open generic viewmodel with one view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348530/how-do-i-configure-caliburn-for-an-open-generic-viewmodel-with-one-view)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [Caliburn used to exist](https://caliburn.codeplex.com/) but eventually became Caliburn.Micro. [Documentation still exists](https://caliburn.codeplex.com/documentation) and it's probably still used out in the wild, so I wouldn't necessarily say that all questions tagged with [caliburn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caliburn) really mean [caliburn.micro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caliburn.micro).

Of course, there [does appear to be some overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caliburn+caliburn.micro).

I think it'd be better if the tag excerpt and wiki for [caliburn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caliburn) was updated to mention that [caliburn.micro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caliburn.micro) exists. They are clearly different tags, and they appear to be for slightly different projects.

Comment: Fair enough! I didn't take in consideration that it could still be used, which is more than a valid point.