# Deciding between [retag-request] and [synonym-request]

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, tag-synonym-process

I was about to request the addition of [angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2) and [angular-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-2) as a synonym of [angularjs-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-2.0) here on meta, when I found a question asking almost the same thing, but instead of requesting a synonym, [it was requesting a retag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291525/1064325).

That was kind of unexpected for me. Then, I took a look at their corresponding descriptions:

> **[retag-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/retag-request)**
>
> This tag is for requests to replace one tag with another existing tag. It also applies to requests that one tag should be merged into another, or simply abandoned.
>
> **[synonym-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/synonym-request)**
>
> A request to add one tag as the synonym of another tag. Please be specific about which tag should be a synonym of which. Bidirectional synonyms and cycles are implicitly disallowed, so suggest wisely.

Unfortunately, it didn't help much to understand the differences, the purpose, and the consequences of each request type.

Also, I've noticed that there are a lot of "Merge/Synonym requests" on meta (for example: [Merge/Synonym request: [caliburn] and [caliburn.micro]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287376/1064325)), which might confirm that it is kind of hard to fully understand and decide which action we should request.

So, what exactly differ a retag from a synonym?

Comment: I think they address the same problem. However, [synonym-request] usually requires mod help as there are not many people voting on tag synonym suggestions. So if the number of questions is small enough, we make it a [retag-request] for possible community cleanup efforts.

Comment: @approxiblue Does it mean that [tag:retag-request]s are not future-proof?

Comment: No, they're not. Example: [We gave \[bootstrap\] the boot, but it wasn't heavy enough!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309933/we-gave-bootstrap-the-boot-but-it-wasnt-heavy-enough)

Comment: @approxiblue The bootstrap example seems more like a [tag:tag-disambiguation]. Anyway, if I got it right, the AngularJS 2.0 example would make more sense if it were a synonym request, since all of [tag:angular2] and all of [tag:angular-2] should be [tag:angularjs-2.0]. A retag request would fit better if we needed to see which [tag:angular2] questions should be retagged to [tag:angularjs-2.0] and which shouldn't (supposing a case where [tag:angular2] would really be a different topic, but often misused).

Comment: That makes sense. I forgot that particular [retag-request] case: where you can't simply make a tag a synonym because it's been used for different things.